# System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(...) returned null in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, autocad

I am programming a plugin for AutoCAD using WPF. This is constructor for WPF window dialog. I caught this problem when defining dpiFactor variable:

```
public TentCreationDialog(Commands cmd)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ...

            exControl = new ExControl(this.textBoxAwingWidth, "AwingCreation");

            ...

            double dpiFactor = System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
            UserInterfaceCustomScale(dpiFactor);
        }
```

Does anybody know what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Visual is not loaded yet, thus, you can fix it by executing `FromVisual()` call inside the `Loaded` event like this

```
Loaded += (sender, args) => {
   double dpiFactor = System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(this)?.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11 ?? 0;
   UserInterfaceCustomScale(dpiFactor);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the system DPI scale in Window's constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    double dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip;
}
```

However, please note it does not necessarily match actual DPI scale of Window under Per-Monitor DPI environment.